# MySQL one query grouped by n rows, max and min inside group, possible?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I think there is no question like this.
I need to group rows by n records and get some values of this group.

I think is better to explain with a graphic example:

[image: graphic description of the query I need]

Is possible to do a query like this? if not my solution will be make an script to create another table with this but I don´t like duplicate data at all.

Thanks!!!

Comment: What is the logic for your grouping? Is it just the first 5 rows? Any 5 rows? Top 5 rows when sorted on specific column?

Comment: @clinomaniac it is a kind of get a summary of the data.  Each group of five starting on the first row.

Comment: You can use row number and divide by 5 to use for your group by and then do min and max as required for each column.

Comment: @clinomaniac it is the better solution, I will answer my own solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, thanks you all guys for your answers, thanks to it I found the simple solution.

I simply add an autoincrement column, and then I can group results by integer division by 5.

[image]

And with this query:

```
SELECT id,
   symbol,
   datetime,
   open,
   MAX(high),
   MIN(low),
   SUBSTRING_INDEX( GROUP_CONCAT(CAST(close AS CHAR) ORDER BY datetime DESC), ',', 1 ) AS close 
FROM `table` 
GROUP BY (id-1) DIV 5
```

And the resulting is:

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
set @counter=-1;
select xgroup,max(x) as mx, max(y) as my, avg(value3) as v3,
from
(
select (@counter := @counter +1) as counter, 
   @counter div 5 as xgroup,
   currency, datetime, value1, value2,
   case mod(@counter,5) when 0 then value1 else 00 end as x,
   case mod(@counter,5) when 4 then value2 else 00 end as y,
   mod(@counter,5) as xxx
FROM findata
) name1
group by xgroup;
```

Comment: Thanks! it is very close to the solution.

Answer (score 1):

@jms has the right approach, but you have to be very careful when using variables:

- You should not assign a variable in one expression and then reference it in another in the same `select`.
- To work in the most recent versions of MySQL, I would suggest ordering the data in a subquery.

In addition, there are some other values that you need:

```
select min(col1), min(col2),
       max(case when mod(rn, 5) = 0 then col3 end),
       max(col4), min(col5),
       max(case when mod(rn, 5) or rn = @rn then col6 end),
       max(case when mod(rn, 5) or rn = @rn then col7 end)
from (select (@rn := @rn + 1) as rn, t.*
      from (select t.*
            from t
            order by col1, col2
           ) t cross join
           (select @rn := -1) params
     ) t
group by (@rn div 5);
```

Note the logic is a bit arcane for the last values -- this is to take into account the final group that might not have exactly 5 rows.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and your time, but min(col1) and min(col2) is erroneous, I'm looking for the first row in a group. But it likes very close to my needs.

Answer (score 1):

You need a column that looks like(assuming you want to group every 5 rows)

```
dummy_table
1
1
1
1
1
2
2
2
2
2
...
```

You can do this by using generate_series() if you are using postgre sql by using

```
select t1 from (select generate_series(1,x)) t1, (select generate_series(1,5)) t2;
```

where you can replace x by (total rows/5) i.e. for 100 rows, x = 20. If you are using any other SQL platform, you can just work on creating this dummy table accordingly.

Once you get this dummy_table, join it with your table on row_number of your table with `t1` column of dummy_table(not row_number of dummy_table). Syntax for accessing row number should be straightforward.

[image: With new column]

After the join, group by this `t1` column and do the required aggregation. To do this in a single query, you can do the above in an inner query and do aggregation outside it. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and your time, it is a good solution for this case of five but I need to change this value. Five is an example. Anyway this and other answer gives me the right solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A solution is to introduce some field for grouping rows for aggregative operations.

It can be reached by introducing a user-variable and assigning values that will allow to group rows as required. For example, it can be a row counter divided by grouping chuck size and rounded to nearest upper ceil number:

```
SET @counter=0;
SELECT CEIL((@counter:=@counter+1)/5) AS chunk, MAX(high), MIN(low) FROM `table` GROUP BY chunk;
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/26213224)